# Повлияет ли на работу пользовательские атрибуты без приставки data-

Tags: html

В общем вопрос в заголовке

> Повлияет ли на работу пользовательские атрибуты без приставки data-

Comment: на работу чего должны повлиять атрибуты?

Comment: На совместимость

Comment: совместимость с чем?

Comment: С браузерами конечно

Comment: браузеры весьма толерантно относятся к невалидному html, поэтому то, что им не нравится они обычно просто пропускают

Comment: Все известные мне браузеры поддерживают произвольные атрибуты, в том числе `data-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет не повлияют. Спецификация HTML 5 не предусматривает никаких ограничений на имена атрибутов у элементов. Единственное отличие ваши атрибуты без `data-` не попадут автоматом в `dataset` элемента. Т.е. атрибут вида `data-xxx` применённый к элементу `elem` будет доступен через DOM в виде `elem.dataset.xxx`, подробнее на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Comment: «Спецификация HTML5 не предусматривает никаких ограничений» — ну неправда, [«Authors must not use elements, attributes, or attribute values that are not permitted by this specification or other applicable specifications, as doing so makes it significantly harder for the language to be extended in the future.»](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#elements)

Comment: А что значит `dataset`?

Comment: @Duoxx см. дополненный ответ.